# Multiple nested tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on tabs. Multiple tabs on the same page are working fine now I'm trying to add tab inside the tab. Nested Sub tabs default, current active class, is not coming i have tried using $(this).parent() and $(this).closest() in jquery but not achieve the result.Here I was not used any id's because I want multiple tabs on the same page which is coming dynamically. Can anyone point me in the right direction nested tab default active tab and I have added the current class in HTML but because of for each loop current class is removing. How to target only the current parent tab, not sub nested tabs.

```js
function atscTabs() {
  $('.at-tabs').each(function(index, item) {
    var $mainContainer = $(this);
    var $menuContainer = $(this).find('.at-tabs-nav__item');
    var $label = $(this).find('.at-tab-__title_text');
    var $content = $(this).find('.at-tabs-content__item');

    $content.hide();
    //adding data attribute 
    $label.each(function(idx, ele) {
      $(this).attr('data-target', idx)
    });
    $($menuContainer[0], $label[0]).addClass('current');
    $($content[0]).show();

    //Display current tab content
    $(this).find('.at-tabs-nav__item').click(function(ele) {
      //debugger;
      $(this).closest('.at-tabs').find('.current').removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');
      $(this).find('.at-tab-__title_text').addClass('current');
      $(this).closest('.at-tabs').find('.at-tabs-content:first > .at-tabs-content__item').hide();
      $(this).closest('.at-tabs').find('.at-tabs-content:first > .at-tabs-content__item').eq(parseInt($(this).find('[data-target]').attr('data-target'))).show()
    });
  });
}

atscTabs();
```

```css
.tab-warp {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.at-tabs-nav__item.current {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #3c98ff;
}

.at-tabs-nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 28px 0px;
}

a.at-tabs-title {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
}

.current a.at-tabs-title {
  color: #fff;
}

.at-tabs-nav__item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

.at-tabs-content {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

hr {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}


/* Vertial tabs */

.at-tabs.at-vertical {
  display: flex;
}

.at-vertical .at-tabs-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 28px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-warp">
  <div id="at-tabs-c2a3d74" class="at-tabs">
    <div class="at-tabs-nav">
      <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
        <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
          <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
            <span class="at-tab-__title_text current">Tab #1</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
        <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
          <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
            <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #2</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
        <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
          <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
            <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #3</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-content">
      <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
        <div id="at-tabs-c2a3d74" class="at-tabs">
          <div class="at-tabs-nav">
            <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
              <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
                <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
                  <span class="at-tab-__title_text current">Sub Tab #1</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
              <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
                <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
                  <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Sub Tab #2</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
              <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
                <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
                  <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Sub Tab #3</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="at-tabs-content">
            <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
            </div>
            <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
              ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
            </div>
            <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
              I am item content. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sius, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
      </div>
      <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
        I am item content. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adnec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

click on tabs and again come back to the first tab then nested tab current class is not showing.
[image: current class is missing]

Comment: I'm running your code, and I don't see what the problem is. What exactly is not working?

Comment: @trincot once you click tabs after clicking tabs nested tab `tabs inside tab` current class is not showing. I updated my question have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `find` method will find matches in the whole DOM subtree, so when you apply it to a top level tab, it will also match items in the subtabs.

You can solve this by using the `children` method instead -- sometimes chained to get grandchildren. That way you control at which depth in the DOM tree you want to inspect and modify things.

So change this:

```
$(this).find('.at-tabs-nav__item').click(function(ele) {
  $(this).closest('.at-tabs').find('.current').removeClass('current');
  // ...
```

to:

```
$(this).children('.at-tabs-nav').children('.at-tabs-nav__item').click(function(ele) {
  $(this).closest('.at-tabs').children('.at-tabs-nav')
                             .children('.current').removeClass('current')
                             .children('.current').removeClass('current');
  // ...
```

```js
function atscTabs() {
  $('.at-tabs').each(function(index, item) {
    var $mainContainer = $(this);
    var $menuContainer = $(this).find('.at-tabs-nav__item');
    var $label = $(this).find('.at-tab-__title_text');
    var $content = $(this).find('.at-tabs-content__item');

    $content.hide();
    //adding data attribute 
    $label.each(function(idx, ele) {
      $(this).attr('data-target', idx)
    });
    $($menuContainer[0], $label[0]).addClass('current');
    $($content[0]).show();

    //Display current tab content
    $(this).children('.at-tabs-nav').children('.at-tabs-nav__item').click(function(ele) {
      //debugger;
      $(this).closest('.at-tabs').children('.at-tabs-nav').children('.current').removeClass('current').children('.current').removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');
      $(this).find('.at-tab-__title_text').addClass('current');
      $(this).closest('.at-tabs').find('.at-tabs-content:first > .at-tabs-content__item').hide();
      $(this).closest('.at-tabs').find('.at-tabs-content:first > .at-tabs-content__item').eq(parseInt($(this).find('[data-target]').attr('data-target'))).show();
      ele.stopPropagation();
    });
  });
}

atscTabs();
```

```css
.tab-warp {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.at-tabs-nav__item.current {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #3c98ff;
}

.at-tabs-nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 28px 0px;
}

a.at-tabs-title {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
}

.current a.at-tabs-title {
  color: #fff;
}

.at-tabs-nav__item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

.at-tabs-content {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

hr {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}


/* Vertial tabs */

.at-tabs.at-vertical {
  display: flex;
}

.at-vertical .at-tabs-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 28px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-warp">
  <div id="at-tabs-c2a3d74" class="at-tabs">
    <div class="at-tabs-nav">
      <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
        <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
          <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
            <span class="at-tab-__title_text current">Tab #1</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
        <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
          <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
            <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #2</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
        <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
          <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
            <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #3</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-content">
      <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
        <div id="at-tabs-c2a3d74" class="at-tabs">
          <div class="at-tabs-nav">
            <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
              <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
                <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
                  <span class="at-tab-__title_text current">Sub Tab #1</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
              <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
                <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
                  <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Sub Tab #2</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
              <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
                <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
                  <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Sub Tab #3</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="at-tabs-content">
            <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
            </div>
            <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
              ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
            </div>
            <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
              I am item content. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sius, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
      </div>
      <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
        I am item content. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adnec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-li">
        <a href="#balance" class="tab-li__link">Balance</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-li">
        <a href="#earning" class="tab-li__link">earning</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-li">
        <a href="#redemption" class="tab-li__link">redemption</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<section id="balance" data-tab-content>
    <p class="tab__content">
        Balance section
    </p>
</section>

<section id="earning" data-tab-content class="">
    <p class="tab__content">
        Earning section
    </p>
</section>

<section id="redemption" data-tab-content class="">
    <p class="tab__content">
        Redemption section
    </p>

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-li">
            <a href="#nested1" class="tab-li__link">Nested1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab-li">
            <a href="#nested2" class="tab-li__link">Nested2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab-li">
            <a href="#nested3" class="tab-li__link">Nested3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <section id="nested1" data-tab-content>
        <p class="tab__content">
            Nested-1 section
        </p>
    </section>
    <section id="nested2" data-tab-content>
        <p class="tab__content">
            Nested-2 section
        </p>
    </section>
    <section id="nested3" data-tab-content>
        <p class="tab__content">
            Nested-3 section
        </p>
    </section>
</section>
```

Style:

```
<style>
[data-tab-content] {
  display: none;
}

.active[data-tab-content] {
  display: block;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tab {
  flex: 1;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #CDCDCD;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
}

.tab.active {
  color: #1BABF9;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1BABF9;
}

.tab-li {
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tab-li a {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color:#CDCDCD;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CDCDCD;
  margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.tab-li a.active {
  color: #1BABF9;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1BABF9;
}

.tab-li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

JS:

```
<script>
var nestedTabSelect = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("ul.tabs").forEach(function (tabContainer) {
    let activeLink, activeContent;
    const links = Array.from(tabContainer.querySelectorAll("a"));

    activeLink =
      links.find(function (link) {
        return link.getAttribute("href") === location.hash;
      }) || links[0];
    activeLink.classList.add("active");

    activeContent = document.querySelector(activeLink.getAttribute("href"));
    activeContent.classList.add("active");

    links.forEach(function (link) {
      if (link !== activeLink) {
        const content = document.querySelector(link.getAttribute("href"));
        content.classList.remove("active");
      }
    });

    tabContainer.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      if (e.target.tagName === "A") {
        // Make the old tab inactive.
        activeLink.classList.remove("active");
        activeContent.classList.remove("active");

        // Update the variables with the new link and content.
        activeLink = e.target;
        activeContent = document.querySelector(activeLink.getAttribute("href"));

        // Make the tab active.
        activeLink.classList.add("active");
        activeContent.classList.add("active");

        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
};

nestedTabSelect();
</script>
```

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/Zsoldo/pen/RwErXKL)!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).